# Matlab image processing - replacing dark pixels with neighboring pixels

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I am doing some image processing of the retina images.. I need to replace the blood vessels with background pixels so that I can focus on other aspects of retina. I could not figure out a way to do this. I am using matlab. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having worked extensively with retinal images, I can tell you that what you're proposing is a complex problem in itself. Sure, if you just want a crude method, you can use `imdilate`. But that will affect your entire image, and other structures in the image will change appearance. Something, that is not desirable.

However, if you want to do it properly, you will first need to segment all the blood vessels and create a binary mask. Once you have a binary mask, it's up to you how to fill up the vessel regions. You can either interpolate from the boundaries or calculate a background image and replace the vessel regions with pixels from the background image, etc.

Segmentation of the blood vessels is a challenging problem and you will find a lot of literature concerning that on the internet. Ultimately, you will have to choose how accurate a segmentation you want and build your algorithm accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`imdilate` should do what you want, since it replaces each pixel with the maximum of its neighbors. For more detailed suggestions, I'd need to see images.